# selenium css_selector struggle

Tags: python, selenium, css-selectors

i got a css-selector that reads

`#block-a4e7-et-lists-a4e7-et-lists-content > div > div > div.row > div.col-md-9.col-sm-12.col-lg-9.col-xs-12 > div > div.a4e7-fw-pagination > div:nth-child(5)`

on the webpage

http://www.ecotechnology.at/de/content/ausbildung-weiterbildung-und-gr%C3%BCne-stellenangebote?etsv=karriere_at

but even after long struggle i do not manage to access it with selenium's
`driver.find_element_by_css_selector()` function in python.

could you help me with this?

best
anda

Comment: Do you want to use xpath or css-selector only?

Comment: what is that you are trying to access. please be descriptive

Comment: Please show your code, the expected response and the actual response.

Comment: `driver.find_element_by_css_selector()` with provided `CSS` selector returns `<div class="pg-loop">4</div>` on pagination even without waiting. Can you share exception log or more details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector itself is *too fragile* because:

- it heavily relies on direct parent-child relationship and hence the structure of the page
- it uses layout-oriented classes like `col-xs-12` that are usually too broad and have a higher chance to be changed

Instead, I'd use the following CSS selector:

```
.content .a4e7-fw-pagination > div:nth-child(5)
```

You might also be experiencing a timing problem - the element is not yet present when you search for it. The common way to tackle problems like this is an [Explicit Wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits). To be specific, in your case, you might have something like:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".content .a4e7-fw-pagination > div:nth-child(5)")))
```

Comment: alecxe, many thanks for your very helpful comment and the associated explanation. that's what i've been looking for. thanks also to the others for their efforts.